# bluetooth на телефоне сильно глушит wi-fi

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

Купил наушники "Xiaomi Redmi AirDots" и обнаружил что они сильно глушат wi-fi на телефоне.

Телефон "honor 9 lite". (у него wi-fi только 2.4, так что покупка роутера с wi-fi на частоте 5 и новым телефоном к нему в придачу из-за наушников за 2000 рублей очень накладно будет...)

На роутере уже выставлял ширину канала в 20мГц

Интервал маяка в 40 выставлял

каналы через анализатор смотрел, выставлял лучшие, и ничего... скорость приема при включенных наушниках 0,25 (без наушников ~90 мбит)... видео на ютубе даже в 144р тормозят...

Может еще кто знает как скорость wi-fi поднять хотя-бы до 10-20 мбит?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поковыряться в настройках разработчика. Если ничего не выйдет то попробуйте вносить изменения уже в build.prop, на 4пда можете в теме аппарата поискать, возможно уже было решение вашей проблемы. Насчет build.prop вам подскажет гугл.

Comment: "Попробуйте поковыряться в настройках разработчика" как туда попасть? это в телефоне?

Comment: @Руслан нажмите 7 раз по номеру сборки в "Настройки -> О телефоне" и у вас должен появиться пункт для разработчика.